# "I was...and I was..." and/or "I was...and was..."?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Take for example the two sentences:

"I was at the park and I was wondering about the future."

"I was at the park and was wondering about the future."

I hear the two being used interchangeably in spoken English all the time. However, are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, they are both grammatically correct. You need to learn about [Conjunction Reduction, which deletes repeated parts of conjoined clauses](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20Conjunction%20Reduction). In this case, _I_ is deleted in the second clause. Conjunction Reduction could also delete the repeated _was_: "I was at the park and wondering about the future". It's an iterative optional rule.

Comment: The second 'was' (after 'and') can be avoided.

Comment: You could also elide _and_: _I was at the park, wondering about the future_, although there are slight differences in nuance.